# itextsharp dropdownlist all values

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

To Whom It May Concern:

I am using itextsharp to export my WebForm to PDF file. The problem I am having is to only export what is visible on the WebForm i.e the selected value of a dropdownlist.

The dropdownlist has 3 values, AAA, BBB, CCC, when you select AAA and export to PDF it shows all 3 value in the PDF not just the selected value of the dropdownlist.

Below the Code of the export button:

```
Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    'DropDownList1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    DropDownList1.RenderControl(hw)
    'Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your code uses `HTMLWorker`, which is obsolete and you should use `XMLWorker`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your code uses `HTMLWorker`, which is obsolete and you should use `XMLWorker`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your code uses `HTMLWorker`, which is obsolete and you should use `XMLWorker`.